# how to achieve immutability in Java 8 stream api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, immutability

Consider the following code. I read it is important to achieve immutability in the code while dealing with Stream API. How can we get a list of all the item in lower case with immutability?

```
    List<String> stockList = Arrays.asList("GOOG", "AAPL", "MSFT", "INTC");
    List<String> stockList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    stockList.parallelStream()
            .filter(e -> !e.contains("M"))
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .map(e -> stockList2.add(e))
            .collect(toList());
   stockList2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: String is an immutable already so you are covered there the stockList2 holds new strings created from the strings of stockList

Comment: not what you asked but generally speaking you should use ParallelStream with caution (on simple cases the overhead will be greater than the benefit)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by immutability in this context. Please clarify.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `map()` to add elements to a `List`. `map()` is supposed to transform a `Stream` of elements of one type to a `Stream` of elements of another type.

Use the `List` returned by `collect(Collectors.toList())`:

```
List<String> stockList2 = 
    stockList.stream()
             .filter(e -> !e.contains("M"))
             .map(String::toLowerCase)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
stockList2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

You are not mutating any objects. The `String`s are already immutable (`toLowerCase` produces a new `String` if necessary) and the original `List` (`stockList`) is not mutated by the creation of the output `List` (`stockList2`).